# UserDefault always return nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, watchkit, userdefaults

`UserDefaults` are not working in my App. Please find the below code under `AppDelegate` file.

```
let sharingData = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.macuser79.xxx");
sharingData?.set("vincenzo", forKey:"username");
sharingData?.synchronize();
```

In the InterfaceController of the app to Watch, to be able to retrieve the value so I did this:

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
let sharingData = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.macuser79.xxx");

let username = sharingData?.object(forKey: "username");
    print("Value username \(username)");
}
```

Please let me know, what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Alternate solution : Use GenericKeychain. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: First thing to look at is make that `group.macuser79.xxx` group is defined in project's capabilities tab in both targets.

Comment: @Otávio. Hello, I checked if the group is defined in both the target and have been defined. Have been defined both within the target of the iPhone, both within the target <MyApp> Watch, is defined inside the <MyApp> Watch Extensions and it all seems ok. I've also updated the provisioning profile but unfortunately nothing.

Comment: Hmm, this code is a direct port from my code written in Objective-C so I can't spot any mistake.
Is `sharingData` object not nil in both cases?

Comment: @Otávio I'm sorry, but I didn't think it was your code, in fact I have found many examples where it is shown how to write the code.
However, the object is not null in both cases.

Comment: I did not mean that you ported it from my code. Just wanted to point out that my code and your code are pretty much the same so I can't clearly see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Otávio If you want I can put all of your code, both the AppDelegate both as a way to recover the information inside of the app's WatchKit, but I believe that it is so trivial the thing, that I can not understand what mistake. I think that is a problem of the simulator, in fact I noticed that the requests to a remote URL are null, or are a long time, about 10 minutes, while the same request is made with the simulator iPhone is very fast

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I did not mean I have ownership of the code, not at all. I just wanted to **compare** your implementation to mine, and they both **happen** (Totally by chance and due being a trivial code) to be the same. No need to remove any code. As you said, this code is even inside Apple's sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128072/discussion-between-macuser-and-otavio).

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift3` `UserDefaults` made much smarter to obtained stored value. In below line, you are storing `String` value without specifying it!:

```
sharingData?.set("vincenzo", forKey:"username");
```

So, in order to get that, you need to write like below:

```
let username = sharingData?.string(forKey: "username");
    print("Value username \(username)");
}
```

This is much more better context in getting values based on you Store.

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your answer but unfortunately it does not work. I've corrected my code as I have indicated, but unfortunately the value is always nil. I have also started the app on the simulator of iPhone but unfortunately no, it does not work.

Comment: Hello,
I did some research on the internet and in this link the user is having the same problem that I am having I also.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808319/swift-3-ios-10-todayextension-userdefaults-always-returns-nil

It should be a problem of the simulator of the apple Watch. Now how do I resolve so that I can try to test my app ? I was left with only one out and then I can publish.
Thanks,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard 
defaults.set("group.macuser79.xxx", forKey:"username")
defaults.synchronize()
```

To access the store:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let username = defaults.string(forKey: "username")
```

I admit that I haven't tried to `init()` my own `UserDefaults` instance before, but the standard instance of it, which is made into a singleton by iOS, is good practice to use.

Also, don't forget to unwrap the optional properly.

Comment: Hi, I tried with your instructions but unfortunately it is always nil

Comment: Apologies! Read this for some more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025526/passing-data-to-apple-watch-app/32002403#32002403

Comment: Hello,
I did some research on the internet and in this link the user is having the same problem that I am having I also.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808319/swift-3-ios-10-todayextension-userdefaults-always-returns-nil

It should be a problem of the simulator of the apple Watch. Now how do I resolve so that I can try to test my app ? I was left with only one out and then I can publish.
Thanks,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 0):

To set:

```
UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.macuser79.xxx")?.set("vincenzo", forKey: "username")
```

To access:

```
UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.macuser79.xxx")!.string(forKey: "username")
```

Comment: Hello,
I tried to do what I have indicated but unfortunately it does not work.
At this point I think there is a problem with the simulator because I don't know what else to think.
I'll try a Apple Watch to a friend to figure out if this is the problem or not.
Thanks for your availability.
Vincenzo

Comment: Hello,
I did some research on the internet and in this link the user is having the same problem that I am having I also.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808319/swift-3-ios-10-todayextension-userdefaults-always-returns-nil

It should be a problem of the simulator of the apple Watch. Now how do I resolve so that I can try to test my app ? I was left with only one out and then I can publish.
Thanks,
Vincenzo

Comment: Hello,
I did some research on the internet and in this link the user is having the same problem that I am having I also.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808319/swift-3-ios-10-todayextension-userdefaults-always-returns-nil

It should be a problem of the simulator of the apple Watch. Now how do I resolve so that I can try to test my app ? I was left with only one out and then I can publish.
Thanks,
Vincenzo